# Inclusion of pgfplotstable in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, tikz-external

Is there any way to include a table generated by pgfplotstable in the tikzpicture environment, where other figures generated by pgfplots exist, in order to save them together as one figure with tikzexternalize?
I have tried it, but the placement of the elements is problematic.
If it can't be done, can the tables be saved as a pdf box like the figures, so that they can be included easily in another document?

Comment: put the table in a node?

Comment: Actually, I decided to use the outfile command of pgfplotstable and include the table using input at the real latex file

Comment: @whirlwind Feel free to answer your question yourself. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @whirlwind, care to write a self-answer?

Answer (score 5):

Though OP decided to get the output of [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) and add the resulting table manually, there is nothing wrong with putting the typesetting code inside a node;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\pgfplotstabletypeset[header=false]{
            1 2 3
            4 5 6
        }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```